# Google Picker DocsUploadView.setIncludeFolders(true) sort order?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-picker

I'm using Google Picker to upload files to my Drive and for convenience I'm also using the `DocsUploadView.setIncludeFolders(true)` option. This all works great except in the target folder picker combo box widget all the folders are in some random order that I can't really figure out (see picture below). I was expecting alphabetical. I can't seem to find a sort option in the Google Picker API reference. So, am I missing something or is this a bug or a missing feature?

[image]

Comment: Try setting the DocsView.setMode(DocsViewMode) as in this page: https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/reference

Comment: @KRR: No effect. I don't see how it would since I'm not using a `DocsView` - I'm only uploading files and not picking from any other sources. I had to actually add a `DocsView` to set the mode. Maybe you misunderstood my what I meant by "target folder picker combo box widget". I'll try adding a picture to the question.